# redirect to react-router-dom hosting. For example github

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to make a redirect. It works on devServer, but I can't configure it to work on GitHub.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Main />} />
          <Route path="/started" element={<Started />} />
          <Route path="/404" element={<Error404 />} />
          <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate to="/404" />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: remove `/` in path i should be like this `path="*"` 
`<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/404" />} />`

Comment: I've tried, I understand that / is specified from the parent router and the option above is redundant. However, we are talking about the fact that github plays its own game. When the site starts, it redirects to 404, while the navigation through the Link itself works. But it's worth changing the path in the address bar, github issues its own 404

Answer (score 0):

I used HashRouter and it worked.